# Swapping element class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an element :

```
...
<li class="products active"><a href="" title="Title">test</a></li>
...
```

I want to access this "li" tag and swap the "active" class to "past" class
so the final result would be :

```
...
<li class="products past"><a href="" title="Title">test</a></li>
...
```

What is the easiest / efficient way to achieve this using jQuery ?

Comment: Why is it a "fake" class? At most there are *pseudo* classes, but no fake classes. If you mean that the class has no CSS rule, then it is still a normal class (with no CSS rules ;)).

Comment: Just because I saw an edit that included *pseudo class*: These classes are well defined. Every class that a user can create is just normal class. Nothing else. @jakemcgraw: Good edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("li.active").removeClass("active").addClass("past");
```

Answer (score 5):

It is much simpler to [use `toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), assuming the element already has one or the other.

Just give it both class names:

```
$('.active').toggleClass('past active');
```

If it has `active` (which it will since that is how it is being selected), its `active` class will be removed, and the `past` class will be added.

If you're doing this inside a click handler, it might look like this:

```
$('.products').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('past active');
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TCvQU/

Comment: Nice. I didn't know you could pass multiple classes to toggleClass() in that manner.

Comment: I´m just guessing here, but because it also has another class, `.products`, I don´t think it´s either `.active` or `.past`; `.past` might be something like *previously selected*...

Comment: ... But I do agree with @jsumners

Comment: @jeroen: It sort of seems that way, but that's not the way it works. The add/remove/toggleClass methods work on them as individual classes instead of the entire "class" attribute. I added an example to the answer. (Unless I'm misunderstanding what you meant.)

Comment: [...here's an updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/TCvQU/1/) showing that the `products` class stays in tact.

Comment: @patrick Also, maybe a check beforehand: `$(this).is('.past:not(.active)') && $(this).toggleClass('past active');`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: True, if there's a chance that one or the other won't be there (or both are there), then additional care needs to be taken. If it is such that there will always be one or the other, then it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @patrick dw With your click handler example, if a `.product` element does not have either class, it will get both classes at once, won´t it?

Comment: @patrick The problem with jQuery's toggle methods is that you cannot know (when reading the code) if they are on-switches or off-switches. If they are used as both (as toggles), then no check is needed. But in this specific case, we want to turn off `.active` and turn on `.past`, so a check should be mandatory (I believe). Even if we are certain that we will at all times execute the code on the "correct" elements (elements that have the .active class but not the .past class), the check should still exist for safety reasons... and for code-readability/clearness.

Comment: @jereon: Yes that's true. That was just a guess at the use here. I noted at the top of my answer that it assumes that the element has one or the other. If that's not the case, then `toggleClass()` is not the right approach.

Comment: @patrick dw I know :-) That´s what my first comment referred to, I am guessing there´s a lot of items and optionally 1 `.active` and 1 `.past` item. I guess my comment was a bit vague.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: The `click` example was just an example of how it could be used for toggling a class. I don't know the specific requirements of the application. If OP wanted to make all `.active` elements `past`, then the first example would be used.

Comment: @jereon: Yes, could be. The question doesn't get into too many specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to modify the selector so it only grabs the correct `li(s)`...

```
$('li').removeClass('active').addClass('past');
```

Perhaps to `$('li.active');`

Answer (score 1):

With your current markup you would do something like:

```
$('li.active').removeClass('active').addClass('past');
```

If you want to change a specific list item element, though, then you will need to identify it somehow. Maybe something like:

```
<li class="products active" id="item1">..</li>
```

And then you can do:

```
$('#item1').removeClass('active').addClass('past');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.active').addClass('past').removeClass('active')
```

Comment: This would involve looking up all elements that have the "active" class twice. Chaining the operations "addClass" and "removeClass" reduces the document queries to one.

Comment: Would be good to make use of method chaining, would mean you don't have to find `.active` twice :-)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with all three answers. Above with the expection that we do not know if your are running your JQuery pure or as part of a CMS which may require some tag changing.

Comment: That's not really an answer, is it?

Comment: Well how can you give him the correct answer if he is using smarty for php the each operation needs to have '$J' instead of just '$'. If he using some other type of framework it maybe something else instead of '$'. So instead of repeating the three possibilities with '$J' in each line of code I just put there maybe a need to change the starting tag.